# Convert tex to html with a xltabular

Tags: latex

I am trying to convert from tex to html. For this I use htlatex with the following command.

`htlatex.exe %FILENAME%.tex "xhtml,html5,mathml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"`

In my tex file I use an xltabular. I get the following error message.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \ar:cnt
l.382 \end{xltabular}
```

That is the code of the xltabular

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{l}
Test1\\
Test2
\end{xltabular}
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem lies I have no idea where the problem is. I can convert it to PDF without any problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That I allready did :-) But I found nothing about that error.

Comment: Yes, but which count :-) I have here only one column and the rows should hopefully not be the problem^^

Comment: I only have one column so I don't need to specify two.